# Collapsing Custom view based on recycler view or scroll view movement using Motion Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, animation, android-motionlayout

I am trying to implement animation using Motion layout.

**Agenda:**

On scrolling recycler view or scroll view, custom view should collapse and show only required end layout.

**start layout**

[image]

**end layout**

[image]

end layout

**activity_main_start.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assetValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="250 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/assetValue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Total Returns"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invested"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyText"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="200 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="300 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main_end.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scrollView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assetValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="250 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main_scene.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@layout/activity_main_end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@layout/activity_main_start">
    <OnSwipe
        app:touchAnchorSide="top"
        app:dragDirection="dragUp" />
</Transition>

 </MotionScene>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assetValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="250 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/assetValue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Total Returns"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invested"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyText"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="200 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dummyText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="300 Rupees"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in rep in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

While scrolling end layout is not getting executing in motion layout.Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research,I had found exact one which I am searching for.Please check below article.

https://riggaroo.dev/android-motionlayout-tutorial-collapsing-view/